# Быстрое преобразование неупорядоченных данных в упорядоченные

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Для начала дисклеймер, речь НЕ про сортировку.

Допустим, есть набор чисел. Можно создать массив, перечислив в нем эти числа (например M[3]={123, 8, 5867} ), а затем получать их, просто обращаясь к массиву по индексу.

```
0 -> 123 
1 -> 8
2 -> 5867
```

Тривиально.

Возможно ли (фундаментально) обратное решение? Так же тривиально преобразовывать значение массива в индекс?

```
123  -> 0 
8    -> 1 
5867 -> 2
```

Понятно, что можно, например, отсортировать массив, а затем делать поиск по нему. Но это все таки некоторая процедура (и затраты времени), а хотелось бы решение, которое позволяло бы это делать, условно, за одну операцию.

Comment: "В одну операцию" - точно нет. Нужен поиск. А искомое значение должно содержаться в массиве только в одном экземпляре. Поиск в отсортированном массиве можно сделать быстрее, чем в неотсортированном, если применить бинарный поиск.

Comment: Конечно возможно. Делаете аналогичный массив, в котором в по индексу 8 хранится 1, по 123 0, по 5867 2.

Comment: .. или заводите аналогичный словарь, ключ-значение.

Comment: Выглядит как `std::map`, крякает как `std::map`

Comment: `std::unordered_map` позволяет обратиться к элементу за время O(1). Но, в отличии от массива,   поддерживает разреженные данные.

Comment: Да, это называется `reversed map`. Её (структуру) построить можно однажды, когда все необходимые данные будут доступны. Либо наращивать одновременно с основным массивом.